# Using Visual Basic variables in a HTML editable form

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am new to VB and programming and I am working with a SQL database. I am trying to make a system where I can add, delete, edit the database through VB web application. I have successfully setup scripts to view the database contents, delete rows, and add content. However I am having trouble creating a "Edit/Update" script. In PHP I would just SELECT * from the database, store as variables and then fill in the HTML form with those variables. Then the user can change what he/she wants and then the UPDATE query would update the database.

I am unsure how to do this with VB. I am having hard time pulling the values from the database and storing into its own VB variables, and I am unsure how I would put these variables into the HTML form to let users edit them.

Here is a form.

```
<form ACTION="update.aspx" METHOD="get">
<b><center><h2>Edit a Name</h2>
First Name: <input TYPE="text" NAME="firstname">
<p>
Last Name: <input TYPE="text" NAME="lastname">
<input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Edit Name">
</form>
```

I need to be able to put the variables retrieved through SQL using VB into this form.

Comment: WOW no I am not. Where did I say I did?

Comment: The concepts are the same, but the techniques different. You might get the best results by spending time with a tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have some code, please add it to the question.

Comment: added code. I have tried nothing, not finding anything in Google

Comment: Russ is right.  You need a basic intro to VB.NET and ASP.NET codebehind. What you're trying to do is not complicated, and you'll probably figure it out within minutes once you actually start on a tutorial.  

But StackOverflow isn't really the best tool for you to use for very general help like this.  This forum's purpose is to provide answers to specific programming questions, so it's not really tailored to what you need.  Best of luck to you though.